# JavaScript: for loop append element in several places

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that needs to append a list item to two menus sharing the same class name.  The problem is it will only append to one or the other if I reference the index of it or if I use index of I it will only append to the last item.

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>List One</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
<li>List Two</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var menu    = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
var listItem    = document.createElement('li');

for(i=0; i < menu.length; ++i){
    menu[i].appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Is this another weird quirk of JS or am I just missing something?

Comment: There is only one *li*, it can't be in two places at once…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be...

```
var menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
var listItem = document.createElement('li');

for (var i=0; i < menu.length; ++i) {
    menu[i].appendChild(listItem.cloneNode());
    // or menu[i].appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    // the point is, you'll have to create a new element and append it
}
```

As it stands, you just move the same element from one parent `.menu` item to another. Quoting [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the
>   document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new
>   position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent
>   node before appending it to some other node).

Comment: This was it, I have to wait 10 mins to accept your answer

Comment: That's pretty rad, I though clone was specific to jQuery.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign cloneNode is used if you don't have a function (clearly you don't need it) that `return`s a new node Element.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign—jQuery re–implements almost the entire DOM API, it's a fundamental part of its design.